# Update boundaries of patch to exclude land with cartopy

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas, cartopy

Quick but maybe difficult question: I've drawn a map which includes a box over the eastern Atlantic, created using a matplotlib patch. I wish to change the shape of the box so that the only area included is the ocean – essentially, I want to mask out Africa and Europe so that they still appear, but that my boxes don't include land. This image is what I currently have,

[image: Current bounds]

which was drawn with the below code:

```
ax.set_extent([5, -150, 0, 80], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.OCEAN, zorder=0)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND, zorder=0, edgecolor='black')
gl = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True, linewidth=0.5, alpha=0.4, color='k',
                  linestyle='--')
ax.add_patch(mpatches.Rectangle(xy=[-30, 20], width=25, height=30,
                                facecolor='none', edgecolor='r',
                                linewidth=2,
                                transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()))
```

and something like this is what I want.

[image: Desired bounds]

Is this even possible in cartopy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this question is difficult. However, I managed to get the result that should be considered a good one.

```
import numpy as np, geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy
#from matplotlib import patches as mpatches
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

# Get world coastlines as a geo dataframe `gdf1`
gdf1 = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
gdf1 = gdf1.dissolve()  # dissolve into 1 geometry
world_landmass = gdf1.geometry[0]  # get the geometry

# Define the CRS for plotting
# Try: ccrs.PlateCarree(), ccrs.Robinson()
use_proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,4), subplot_kw=dict(projection=use_proj))

ax.set_extent([-35, 0, 15, 55], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.OCEAN, zorder=0)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND, zorder=0, edgecolor='black')

# Draw gridlines
gl = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True, linewidth=0.5, alpha=0.4, color='k',
                  linestyle='--')

# Create the rectangle shape
# I use Polygon object, so that, it can be spatially manipulated easily
x0, y0 = -30, 20
w, h = 25, 30
rect = Polygon([(x0, y0), (x0, y0+h), (x0+w, y0+h), (x0+w, y0)])

# Spatially subtract the rectangle by the land_mass
poly_cut = rect.difference(world_landmass)

# Add the result to the plot
# Use fc="none" to get transparent areas
ax.add_geometries([poly_cut], fc="white", ec='red', alpha=0.7, lw=5, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

[image: plot1]

If `use_proj = ccrs.Robinson()` is used, the plot will be.

[image: plot2]